# Annotate Point and Text to R googleVis gvisAreaChart

Tags: r, plot, google-visualization, googlevis

I am just wondering if there is any possibility that I can add a point and text in Area chart of GoogleVis R. Let say I have below GoogleVis plot:

```
library(googleVis)

df=data.frame(country=c("US", "GB", "BR"), 
              val1=c(10,13,14), 
              val2=c(23,12,32))

plot(gvisAreaChart(df))
```

Now I want to add a point with below coordinate
(x = 'GB', y = 30) and a Text next to that point 'Look this Point'

Comment: ?gvisMerge not really merging, it just putting various plots next to each other or below to each other. What I am looking for is a single plot with Annotation (point and text)

Comment: I didn't get the text part. Will modify my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your data should be set up like this:

```
df=data.frame(country=c("US", "GB", "BR"), 
              val1=c(10,13,14), 
              val2=c(23,12,32),
              point=c(NA,30,NA))
```

You would probably want a `gvisComboChart`:

```
Combo <- gvisComboChart(df, xvar = "country",
                    yvar=c("val1","val2","point"),
                    options = list(seriesType="Area",
                                   series='{3:{type:"Scatter"}}'))
```

And this would be output:

[image]

Comment: This works. However below simplified code 'plot(gvisAreaChart(df))' also generates same plot based on your modified 'df'. One quick Q : Can we disable all hover-tooltips except for that Point. Where only a text e.g. 'Look this Point' will be visible upon hovering

Comment: @Bogaso I was thinking about how to add text and haven't had any ideas yet. Let me dig into your suggestion. The only reason I used that `Combo` is that I didn't want the shade below the lines in the legend.

Comment: On searching over net, I found topic related to how to control Tooltip : https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content#specifying-the-tooltip-type. However couldnt understand how to apply it on R context. Any help please?

Comment: I found this but had no success in a time that I could allotted to this; https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleVis/vignettes/Using_Roles_via_googleVis.html

Comment: @Bogaso Also consider using rcharts: http://www.rpubs.com/dnchari/rcharts